# Python/Pandas: How do I take specific columns from the second row of each ID and place it in new columns on the first row of the ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table:

| id | x | y | z | A1_origin | A1_destination | A2_origin | A2_destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 12 | 40 | B | C | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 30 | 12 | 40 | C | D | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 7 | 14 | 12 | E | F | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 7 | 14 | 12 | F | G | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 68 | 16 | 9 | B | D | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 68 | 16 | 9 | D | F | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 72 | 18 | 8 | N | P | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 72 | 18 | 8 | P | Q | NaN | NaN |

I essentially want to "flatten" it so that each ID only appears once (so that the final table looks like this):

| id | x | y | z | A1_origin | A1_destination | A2_origin | A2_destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 12 | 40 | B | C | C | D |
| 2 | 7 | 14 | 12 | E | F | F | G |
| 3 | 68 | 16 | 9 | B | D | D | F |
| 4 | 72 | 18 | 8 | N | P | P | Q |

I've been struggling on how to go about this. I added NaN columns in, but is that necessary? Can I actually get to the end without adding NaN columns? Either way, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each ID appears **exactly** twice, you can do:

```
# mark the first rows
s= df.duplicated('id', keep='last')

# copy second rows to the first rows
df.loc[s, ['A2_origin', 'A2_destination']] = df.loc[~s, ['A1_origin','A1_destination']].values

# drop the second rows
df = df.loc[s]
```

Output:

```
   id   x   y   z A1_origin A1_destination A2_origin A2_destination
0   1  30  12  40        B              C         C              D 
2   2   7  14  12        E              F         F              G 
4   3  68  16   9        B              D         D              F 
6   4  72  18   8        N              P         P              Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
tdf = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','x','y','z'], keep='first')

tdf[['A1_origin', 'A1_destination']] = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','x','y','z'], keep='last')[['A1_origin', 'A1_destination']].reset_index(drop=True)
```